# Decreasing inner box shadow with CSS3

Tags: css

I would like to know if (and maybe how) some text-shadow like shown in following image is possible:

[image]

The shadow is decreasing over several list-elements. I was thinking to give each element different hover-classes depending on what element is being hovered on, but I am not even sure how to get such decreasing shadows with CSS. Would be really cool if someone would be able to teach me how to do that. If you want you can use my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xsven/rbz72/) code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this

## [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/3780722)

(click a tab to select it and see the shadows)

and get the effect using `box-shadow` on pseudo-elements of the selected tab.

Should look like this

[image: chrome 21 on win 7]

**HTML**:

```
<ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#' tabindex='1'>1st tab</a></li>
    <!-- as many tabs as you would like -->
    <li><a href='#' tabindex='1'>aaand another tab</a></li>
</ul>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.tabs { overflow: hidden; margin-top: 7em; list-style: none; }
.tabs li { float: left; border-right: 1px dotted #222; }
.tabs a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em .66em;
    font: .66em/1.1 sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs a:focus {
    z-index: 3;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 -.5em 1.5em black;
    background: lemonchiffon;
}
.tabs a:focus:before, .tabs a:focus:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    width: 30em; height: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px black;
    content: '';
}
.tabs a:before {
    left: -30.5em;
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.tabs a:after {
    right: -30.5em;
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
```

Comment: I've only tested it in Chrome and I'm seeing the shadows. So I must ask what version and what OS?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using and it looks like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/1kFeO.png

Comment: Weird, I don't see any shadows at all.. Good job anyhow :D

Comment: Are you clicking a tab to select it?

Comment: Wow! How fast was that? Works perfectly with Chrome and OSX. Thank you :-)

Comment: I translated into my project: For some reason transform doesn't work here.. :-( Are there any prerequisites for transform to work?

Comment: Did you add the browser prefixes for `transform` and `transform-origin`? The unprefixed version is not supported by any browser yet (though this should change in the near future with IE10, FF16 and Opera 12.5). Dabblet uses -prefix-free which adds them for me, so that I don't write the same thing four or five times with different prefixes.

Comment: You are right! Usually I am using LESS-methods so I am overlooking this quite regularly :S Again thank you, you genious :-D

Answer (score 1):

You could augment an `<li>` to sit within the whole width of the `<ul>`, rotate it and give it a shadow..

HTML:

```
    ...
    </li>
        <li class="shadow">1</li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul
{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
}

li.shadow
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 45px #000;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-1deg);
}
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/4Luet/1/

Comment: Sry I completely overlooked your answer. You got a nice idea here. Thank you.